# Does double less than minus "<<-" sign mean anything in ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am trying to get myself familiar with ruby syntax and coding styles(i am a newbie). I came across a code that uses `<<-`, what does this mean in Ruby? Code is

```
  def expectation_message(expectation)
    <<-FE
      #{expectation.message}
      #{expectation.stack}
    FE
  end
```

This is just a section of the whole code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's ruby heredoc syntax. You can read about it here: http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are various ways to define multi-line string in Ruby. This is one of them.

```
> name = 'John'
> city = 'Ny'
> multiline_string = <<-EOS
> This is the first line
> My name is #{name}.
> My city is #{city} city.
> EOS
 => "This is the first line\nMy name is John.\nMy city is Ny city.\n" 
>
```

the `EOS` in above example is just a convention, you can use any string you like and its case insensitive. Normally the `EOS` means `End Of String`

Moreover, even the `-` (dash) is not needed. However, allows you to indent the "end of here doc" delimiter. See the following example to understand the sentences.

```
2.2.1 :014 > <<EOF
2.2.1 :015"> My first line without dash
2.2.1 :016">         EOF
2.2.1 :017"> EOF
 => "My first line without dash\n        EOF\n" 


2.2.1 :018 > <<-EOF
2.2.1 :019"> My first line with dash. This even supports spaces before the ending delimiter.
2.2.1 :020">    EOF
 => "My first line with dash. This even supports spaces before the ending delimiter.\n" 
2.2.1 :021 >
```

for more info see 
https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/ruby-multiline-string-definition/

Comment: In the OP's case the dash _is_ needed (to allow indented end marker)

Comment: "they all support the Interpolation" - not true. Single quoted strings do not allow interpolation.

Comment: ok make sure you checkmark one of the answers over here when you are done. :)

Comment: The second example, with the `<<-` syntax throws an error for me. I need to assign the value to a variable, otherwise I get a uninitialized constant error.

Comment: An [interesting example](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_0_1/lib/forwardable.rb#L215-L223) of a multiline string.

Answer (score 6):

`<<FE` (you can replace FE with another word) is used to create multi-line strings. `<<-FE` is used to create multi-line strings with the whitespace before the end marker removed.

[More info](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/4438542511/heredoc-and-indent)